How to Determine the State of Matter of a Molecule
While many videos and even answers exist on this site about finding whether a compound is soluble in water to determine if its state symbol should be "(aq)." However, across the internet I can find no actual guide on determining the state of an unknown compound, especially a covalent one. This issue arose because I, for fun, decided to try and find what the properties of $\ce{NeO2}$. I'm well aware that this compound doesn't and (to the best of my knowledge) can't exist. I’m currently searching for what state of matter it would be, as $\ce{XeO2}$ is a solid, but that is a full period lower.

Molecules don't have "the State of Matter". Compounds do, but it obviously depends on temperature, pressure, etc. If you ever found "NeO2" somewhere, that would be likely either high vacuum, or argon matrix.

What meaning is there is trying to establish the physical properties of something which cannot physically exist? Just assume magic and then you can do whatever you want.

Look up "phase diagram".

Most likely it would be a gas at RT and p. Other simple non-metal oxides in the same row ($\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{N2O}$, $\ce{NO}$, $\ce{NO2}$, $\ce{OF2}$) are gases. The central atoms are "hard" and the molecules light and weakly polarizable.
You could probably simulate the compound with ab initio chemistry software by setting constraints on the interatomic distances. You might even obtain force-field model parameters for an MD simulation, but you wouldn't have anything to test it against. You can ask at Matter Modeling SE if this is possible.
